# how to add to list Cyrillic symbols

Tags: python

So i have a problem that script doesn't add Cyrillic symbols to list, i'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\Folder Compare.py", line 23, in 
>       print(list_script)   File "C:\Users\Viktor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
>   line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 6-11: character maps to

I found couple solutions on stack overflow, but they didn't work for me well

```
list1, list2 = ([] for i in range(2))

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('D:\\Folder'):
    for fname in filenames:
        list1.append(fname)


for list_script in list1:
    print(list_script)
```

Comment: I do not think this is the problem. Please provide full error and in particular the line where error does occur.

Comment: @ElisByberi added full error message

Comment: `UnicodeEncodeError` It is not valid Unicode string.

Comment: So the error is  on the `print` line: the Cyrillic symbol has been successfully added, but your system cannot display it. You should say more about your system: python version (2 or 3), os, and default character set

Comment: python 3.6, Windows 10, utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try set PYTHONIOENCODING enviroment variable to 'UTF-8':

```
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = 'UTF-8'
```

or change stdout encoding:

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

Comment: which statement does exactly helps in your case?

Comment: @IvanBryzzhin The second one wouldn't even work because the writer would write bytes after encoding, and sys.stdout is a string stream. You would have to write to `sys.stdout.buffer` then.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that where you are printing has cp1252 encoding. This encoding cannot represent cryllic characters, so it throws an error when you try to print them.

Try to change your terminal encoding.